# How to access result of stored procedure in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

We have create stored procedures and imported using entity framework.

For access result of stored procedure there is option to that to create model for each and every property of stored procedure result and mapping of model.

but is there any other option to directly access result of stored procedure without create model for each stored procedure.

```
public dynamic GetCollection()
{
     var lstChkResult = _db.SPGetCollection().ToList();
     return lstChkResult;
}
```

we have tried it by using dynamic keyword ,but it do not support to check count of result.

Comment: Are you want to execute SP without mapping the procedure name as a function in EF, i.e. execute SP with existing POCO class or execute like `SqlConnection` instance does?

Comment: that is another option for  execution of stored procedure in MVC but want to capture result to some dynamic/ var list , so all time no need to create model class for each and every procedure.

Comment: instead of EF use dapper.

Comment: Yes, Dapper. Never (ever) try to use EF for dynamic data structures. It's just not the right tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword dynamic is useful for access stored procedure result which returns single data.

To access dynamic list from a stored procedure in dynamic josnresult object.

dynamic objlist= json.deserialize(jsondata);